# Daisyui Navbar and Drawer Results to Always Showing Scrollbar

Tags: laravel, daisyui

Why is it that there is always a scrollbar in the page?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace("_", "-", app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config("app.name", "Laravel") }}</title>

    @vite(["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"])
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar bg-base-100">
        <div class="flex-1">
            <a class="btn btn-ghost text-xl">daisyUI</a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-none">
            <div class="dropdown dropdown-end">
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-ghost btn-circle">
                    <div class="indicator">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                d="M3 3h2l.4 2M7 13h10l4-8H5.4M7 13L5.4 5M7 13l-2.293 2.293c-.63.63-.184 1.707.707 1.707H17m0 0a2 2 0 100 4 2 2 0 000-4zm-8 2a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        <span class="badge badge-sm indicator-item">8</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div tabindex="0" class="mt-3 z-[1] card card-compact dropdown-content w-52 bg-base-100 shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span class="font-bold text-lg">8 Items</span>
                        <span class="text-info">Subtotal: $999</span>
                        <div class="card-actions">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown dropdown-end">
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-ghost btn-circle avatar">
                    <div class="w-10 rounded-full">
                        <img alt="Tailwind CSS Navbar component"
                            src="https://daisyui.com/images/stock/photo-1534528741775-53994a69daeb.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul tabindex="0"
                    class="menu menu-sm dropdown-content mt-3 z-[1] p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52">
                    <li>
                        <a class="justify-between">
                            Profile
                            <span class="badge">New</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a>Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="drawer lg:drawer-open">
        <input id="my-drawer-2" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
        <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <!-- Page content here -->
            <label for="my-drawer-2" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button lg:hidden">Open drawer</label>

        </div>
        <div class="drawer-side">
            <label for="my-drawer-2" aria-label="close sidebar" class="drawer-overlay"></label>
            <ul class="menu p-4 w-80 min-h-full bg-base-200 text-base-content">
                <!-- Sidebar content here -->
                <li><a>Sidebar Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Sidebar Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]